# Angular ng-repeat custom filter giving unresolved variable

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to complete this custom filter to filter a list of all "savings" created in the last 24 hours

Controller filter

```
    angular.module('savings').filter('lessThan', function () {
    return function(savings, requirement) {

        var filterKey = Object.keys(requirement)[0];
        var filterVal = requirement[filterKey];

        var filtered = [];

        if(filterVal !== undefined && filterVal !== ''){
            angular.forEach(savings, function(saving) {

                var today = new Date();
                var date = new Date(saving.created.$date); <-- Unresolved variable $date
                alert(date);
                var diff = today - date;

                diff = diff / (1000*60*60);

                if(diff < filterVal) {
                    filtered.push(saving);
                }
            });
            return filtered;

        }

        return savings;

    };
});
```

And here is how i call it from the view

```
<div ng-repeat="saving in savings |  orderBy: '-votesreal' | limitTo:6 | lessThan: {'created.$date':24}" class="col-lg-2 no-padding-spotlight text-center">

        <div class=" thumbnail-spotlight thumbnail centred-image">
          <img src="{{saving.image}}" /><br>
          <a class="text-center" ng-href="/savings/{{saving._id}}" ng-bind="saving.title +' (&euro;'+  saving.price +' @ '+  saving.retailer+')'"></a>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Ive wrote a note where the unresolved variable is. How do i declare the "saving" object which is coming from the database. Without the filter it returns all results fine.

Controller Code

```
    angular.module('savings').controller('SavingsController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$stateParams', '$location', '$window', 'Authentication', 'Savings', 'FileUploader',
        function($scope, $timeout, $stateParams,  $location, $window, Authentication, Savings, FileUploader) {

            $scope.authentication = Authentication;
            $scope.user = Authentication.user;
            $scope.savingImageURL = '/modules/users/client/img/profile/saveme-placeholder.png';
            // $scope.user.imageURL  = '/modules/users/client/img/profile/saveme-placeholder.png';
            $scope.imageURL1 = '';
            $scope.hottestsorted = true;
            $scope.newestsorted = true;
            $scope.brandLogo = '/modules/users/client/img/profile/argos-logo.png';
            $scope.spotlightSort = Savings.votesreal;
             $scope.savings = Savings;
            //$scope.user.imageURL = '';
            $scope.submitFormSaving = function(isValid) {
                $scope.submitted = true;
            };

    }
]);
```

Client.service

```
    //Savings service used for communicating with the savings REST endpoints
angular.module('savings').factory('Savings', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/savings/:savingId', {
      savingId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: You're missing the two most important pieces of code.. include your controller code and your Savings factory code.

Comment: is that the correct code?

Comment: Shouldn't there be this line in your controller: `$scope.savings = Savings;` ?

Comment: There is no $scope.savings.. is there another controller?

Comment: No other controller. It still says that its unresolved for saving.created.$date and returns no results. If i declare an array called savings with values it disappears and works fine.

Comment: Right because you don't have any savings property in your scope unless you declare it. You need to include your Savings service as well

Comment: So i have to add to the Client.service file posted above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's good to see that $scope.savings has snuck in there. Try something like this:

Instead of `$scope.savings = Savings;` use:

```
Savings.query({}, function(resp){
  console.log(resp);
  $scope.savings = resp;        
});
```

If your api endpoint needs the savingId use:

```
Savings.query({ savingId: [something] }, function(resp){
  console.log(resp);
  $scope.savings = resp;        
});
```

This should work for you.

Comment: That console.log is printing out all the Objects properly so the problem must be somewhere else. maybe i have the filter wrong. Im gonna post the controller to pastebin.Is this the correct way to add the filter? http://pastebin.com/t3nBmFPn

Comment: The filter is dependent on the data structure so I would need to see the response.

Comment: Chrome doesnt seem to let me copy and paste so heres a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/M1jMOe3.png

Comment: OK this question is answered now and you can mark it. Can you post that image on your other question and I'll update that answer.